# How to open SMS setting Activity in our application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, android-ndk

In following code I only able to open compose SMS.....

I want to open SMS setting activity without option menu is pressed..

```
`String SMS_MIME_TYPE = "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms";

    Intent defineIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);                

    defineIntent.setType(SMS_MIME_TYPE);`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in the Android SDK for this.

You are welcome to contact the developers of each of the hundreds of SMS clients, asking them if they have a documented and supported means of launching their settings activity from outside their app. The app in the Android open source project does not have such a means -- that app's Settings activity can only be opened by the app itself, not by third parties.